# Can WebSockets and HTTP server both run on the SAME port number?

Tags: java, http, websocket, glassfish-4

I have been using GlassFish server, where, index.html is sending the control to  servlet file which is sending the control to another nextStep.html file, which is working on WebSockets. Right now, I am confused, as I am getting an error:

> WebSocket connection to 'LocalHost-link' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

I think this problem is related to port numbers.
Can we use both WebSockets and HTTP server on the same port, if yes, then How ?
If we have to use different ports, then how to perform this task in Java ?

Comment: Yes it can run on the same port, in fact it must run on the same port; the raison d'etre of websocket handshake is so that the websocket can run on the same connection without confusing intermediaries that doesn't understand websocket.

Comment: @LieRyan ok. While running the websockets on the same port, I am getting an error: `Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404` , can you guide me how to resolve this ?

Comment: Your web server must understand websocket and must expect a websocket connection on the URL you're connecting to. You are getting 404 Not Found because the server is not expecting a websocket request on that URL.

Comment: Or the websocket uri is incorrect ...

Comment: @manpreetSingh how did you do that? i am facing the same issue.

Comment: @Swaprks: Hi, actually I don't remember exactly how I solved this one, but here is the link to the Git repo, I hope it helps.
https://github.com/manpreetSinghkhalsa/CollabEdit2.0

Answer (score 16):

To provide this question with an answer: Yes, they can.

**See also:**

- [Is it possible to enable tcp, http and websocket all using the same port?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13791050/is-it-possible-to-enable-tcp-http-and-websocket-all-using-the-same-port)
- [Running a websocket server and a http server on the same server](https://serverfault.com/questions/575467/running-a-websocket-server-and-a-http-server-on-the-same-server)