# Connect Azure Web App Bot to an external chat service that is not in the Channel list?

Tags: websocket

For instance, Mixer's chat API requires bots to listen on a web socket, but Azure App Bots require apps to post to messages to it.

Comment: Please check out the Direct Line SDK: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-direct-line-3-0-concepts

Comment: I have looked at that, and it appeared to be for clients directly sending messages to the Web App Bot, not connecting it to an existing chat service.

Answer (score 0):

The bot is essentially an API server. The `/api/messages` route is one endpoint. You may define as many endpoints as you like on your bot server to handle whatever other activities you need to handle, such as websockets.

Comment: but how would I get it to listen to the web socket?

Comment: @jjthemachine - Just run your websocket endpoint on a different route like `/api/websockets`. Or you, if you are inspired, you can configure them to run on the same route, same port as described in this discussion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13791050/is-it-possible-to-enable-tcp-http-and-websocket-all-using-the-same-port -- This is not a Bot Framework specific issue, just a normal server-side config issue.